# is there a way in autoit script to find if current file was included or it is running on its own?

Tags: include, autoit

I mean something like `get_included_files();` in php or `Error().stack;` in javascript or `$BASH_SOURCE` array in bash ?

I've only found in macros ( https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm ) `@ScriptFullPath` and `@ScriptName`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `@ScriptName` matches the name of the current script. If it doesn't your script has been included in something else. I use this method to run a unit test if an included script is run as a stand alone script. I add the following code to the end of included_script.au3:

```
; unit test code
If @ScriptName == "included_script.au3" Then
    MsgBox(0, "Unit Test", "Running unit test...", 3)
    test()
    Exit
EndIf

Func test()
    ; no test defined
EndFunc
```

When included in a "main.au3" file, the `@ScriptName` will be set to "main.au3" and it will not run `test()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the functionality by using a global variable.  Say `$includeDepth`.  `$includeDepth` should be incremented by 1 before any `#include` and decremented by 1 after it.  If `$includeDepth` is `0`, then the code is not running as part of an `#include`.  For example:

```
Global $includeDepth
$includeDepth+= 1
#include <MyScript1.au3>
#include <MyScript2.au3>
$includeDepth-= 1

; Declarations, functions, and initializations to be run in both "include" and "non-include" modes

If $includeDepth <= 0 Then
    ; Code for when in "non-include" mode
EndIf
```

You need to be very consistent in this usage, though.  However, as long as library `#include`s don't include your own scripts (or scripts where this checking is done), there is no need to modify them.  From this point of view, it's also not necessary to increment/decrement `$includeDepth` while including library `#include`s.  However, it doesn't hurt and it reinforces the practice.